# How to filter out values from array

Tags: jq

I have an object that looks like this: `{"m":["bad-1", "ok", "also-ok", "bad-2", "bad-3"]}` I would like to keep just the values in `m` that don't start with `bad-`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In this case you could also use startswith/1
2. You can also use map/1, select/1 and not/0
3. You can update the "m" slot in-place using |=

Thus:

```
.m |= map( select( startswith("bad-") | not ))
```

produces:

```
{
  "m": [
    "ok",
    "also-ok"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses regular expressions and the `reduce` operator:

`reduce .[] as $item ([]; if ($item | test("^bad-")) then .  else . + [$item] end)`

Things I learned:

1. the `reduce` operator
2. you can pipe 'subitems' through filters (above `$item | test("^bad")`)